# Public fields for Java compatibility

Tags: field, kotlin, member, public

I found recent interest in Kotlin as a language, because the platform we develop for is Java 6 based and hence lacks any syntactic sugar the recent years brought to Java.

There's but one thing that makes it impossible to use Kotlin over Java in development, that is, the platform we develop for uses some reflection internally and requires members to be public. It won't work otherwise.

So, the bytecode generated from the Kotlin file in fact produces public getters and setters, the fields themselves yet remain private.

**Is there a way to overcome this, so I get real public fields?**

I am aware of the design failure that requires public fields, but the system is kind of a black box to us, we cannot change the fact that it has to be this way.

Comment: Could the annotation `@JvmField` work for you?

Comment: That's it! Sweet! So easy. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html, "member" refers to both, methods and fields. What you probably mean are "fields". I've edited the question.

Comment: @marstran Consider making your comment an answer so that the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The annotation `@JvmField` should help you. It makes the Kotlin-compiler expose the property as a field on the JVM. See here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/