# Kotlin / Java use enum in a switch statement of type Int

Tags: java, kotlin

For an Android project, I have a .kt file:

```
class foo () {
    enum class animal (var Id: Int) {
        CAT(0),
        DOG(1),
        FISH(2),
    }
}
```

And a .java file, where the problem occurs:

```
public void processAnimal(int animalId) {
    switch(animalId) {
        case foo.animal.CAT.Id:
            //do something
            break;
        case foo.animal.DOG.Id:
            //do something else
            break;
        case foo.animal.FISH.Id:
            //do something fishy
            break;
    }
}
```

On the `.Id` it gives an error 'Id has private access in foo.animal', so that does not work.

Changing `.Id` to `.getId()` gives 'Constant expression required' because of the switch statement.

It is a requirement out of my control for the type to be `int` instead of `animal` in the signature `public void processAnimal(int animalId) {` and this would be the correct solution if it were not out of my control.

Marking fields as public in the .kt file changes nothing.

Is there a way to achieve what I am setting out to do?

Thank you!

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039875/public-fields-for-java-compatibility

But I cannot make it work.

Comment: You have to use `getId()` in java. Kotlin member variables are not raw fields they are getter and setters, the backing field or actual variable is always private (unless you use @JvmField annotation).

Comment: Yeah, which is not static. But unfortunately even if I change `enum class animal (var Id: Int) {` to `enum class animal (@JvmField var Id: Int) {` then the error changes to 'Constant expression required' so apparently even .Id is not static.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I can think of making this work (due to the java switch limitations) is to create a helper function in the enum class itself that will allow us to translate that `Id` into an enum `Value`.

The java function would be:

```
public void processAnimal(int animalId) {
    AnimalEnum animalEnum = AnimalEnum.fromInt(animalId);
    switch(animalEnum) {
        case CAT:
            //do something
            break;
        case DOG:
            //do something else
            break;
        case FISH:
            //do something fishy
            break;
    }
}
```

And the enum class would look something like this:

```
enum class AnimalEnum(val Id: Int) { //classes should start with an uppercase letter in kotlin
CAT(0),
DOG(1),
FISH(2);

companion object {
    @JvmStatic //to be accessible from java
    fun fromInt(givenInt: Int): AnimalEnum {
        return when (givenInt) {
            CAT.Id -> CAT
            DOG.Id -> DOG
            FISH.Id -> FISH
            else -> throw Exception("Invalid id `$givenInt`, available ids are ${values().map { it.Id }}") // or a null or something
        }
    }
}}
```

Another way of writing that fromInt() function would be:

```
companion object {
    private val map = values().associateBy(AnimalEnum::Id)
    @JvmStatic //to be accessible from java
    fun fromInt(givenInt: Int) = map[givenInt] ?: throw Exception("Invalid id `$givenInt`, available ids are ${values().map { it.Id }}") // or a null or something
}
```

The second option is not as readable, but better if we have a lot of enum values

Comment: Looks like you really understand Kotlin, and if you cannot find a simple way, then I think we can safely say that none exists. But I am impressed at the solution nevertheless. Thanks.

Comment: something to remember is that Kotlin works ok with Java, but works a lot better without it. You wouldn't need to do any of that if the enum would be used by Kotlin only functions.